# GCC - Volatile Variable (global vs. local)

Tags: c, variables, gcc, language-lawyer, volatile

In the code below, if I set a global volatile variable (of type `uint8_t`) to `0` and modify it directly by memory manipulation to 1, the program won't go to the asm("nop") statement. If I place the variable in local scope, the same manipulation by memory works perfectly.

Can someone tell me, why this is and/or is this the defined behaviour?

**Not working code:**

```
volatile uint8_t testVolatileVar;

int main(void)
{
    testVolatileVar = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        if (testVolatileVar == 1)
        {
            asm("nop");
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding disassembly (which looks weird to me) is:

```
          main:
push    {r7}
add     r7, sp, #0
        testVolatileVar = 0;
ldr     r3, [pc, #16]   ; (0x200003bc <main+24>)
movs    r2, #0
strb    r2, [r3, #0]
            if (testVolatileVar == 1)
ldr     r3, [pc, #12]   ; (0x200003bc <main+24>)
ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
uxtb    r3, r3
cmp     r3, #1
bne.n   0x200003ae <main+10>
                asm("nop");
nop     
            if (testVolatileVar == 1)
b.n     0x200003ae <main+10>
movs    r0, r7
movs    r0, #32
```

**Working code:**

```
int main(void)
{
    volatile uint8_t testVolatileVar = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        if (testVolatileVar == 1)
        {
            asm("nop");
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding disassembly:

```
          main:
push    {r7}
sub     sp, #12
add     r7, sp, #0
    volatile uint8_t testVolatileVar = 0;
movs    r3, #0
strb    r3, [r7, #7]
        if (testVolatileVar == 1)
ldrb    r3, [r7, #7]
uxtb    r3, r3
cmp     r3, #1
bne.n   0x20000b86 <main+10>
                asm("nop");
nop     
        if (testVolatileVar == 1)
b.n     0x20000b86 <main+10>
```

Screenshots of debugger:

[image: Condition true - but no jump to asm("nop")]

[image: Disassembly Breakpoint]

Disassembly Step Trace:

```
ldr     r3, [pc, #12]   ; (0x200003bc <main+24>)
R3 -> 0x20200038

ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
R3 -> 0

uxtb    r3, r3
R3 -> 0 

cmp     r3, #1
R3 -> 0
```

So the assembly code does what it states - but this shouldn't be the assembly code for that C code at all. Why is a fixed zero loaded into R3?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215167/discussion-on-question-by-sweetsmoke-gcc-volatile-variable-global-vs-local).

Comment: There are still a lot of details missing in this question: what compiler is used, what platform (it seems to be ARM instructions), how did you infer that the memory address of the local variable is 0x20200038 (that doesn't seem right to me), is cache enabled? If you add these details it might be possible to answer the question.